# dynamic lat/lng into Open Layer script

Tags: jquery, openlayers

I have the following dynamic ColdFusion variables:

```
var map_lat = '<%cfoutput%>#map_lat#<%/cfoutput%>';
var map_lng = '<%cfoutput%>#map_lng#<%/cfoutput%>';
```

They return the correct values when alerted.

If I hardcoded these values into the OpenLayers script, it would look like this:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-36.910847, 174.77596]), //hard-coded
          zoom: 4
        })
      });
```

But, I want to enter the variables instead of hardcoding, something like this:

```
var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          })
        ],
        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([map_lng , map_lat]), // variables
          zoom: 4
        })
      });
```

This doesn't work and I've tried everything I can think of to insert these variables in there, including generating an array, creating a string from the array, etc, but nothing works.

Need help with this.

### **UPDATE - SOLVED**

```
var x = parseFloat(map_lng);
var y = parseFloat(map_lat);

var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
       new ol.layer.Tile({
         source: new ol.source.OSM()
       })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
       center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([x,y]),
       zoom: 12
    })
});
```

Comment: Have you tried using JavaCast to cast the array as a Java string array:  javaCast( "char[]",[map_lng,map_lat])

Comment: Some OL function are fussy about the data type. Try `parseFloat(map_lng)`. Also beware of the locale when creating the variable, as OL expect a `.` for the decimals, not a `,`

Comment: @JGH, that's the answer. Create an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some OL functions are really sensitive about the parameter datatype. If it is believed to be a string instead of a float, the function can fail - and often silently.

You can fix it by changing the line

```
center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([map_lng , map_lat]),
```

to

```
center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([parseFloat(map_lng) , parseFloat(map_lat)]),
```